# How to access an object from a method in its class?

Tags: java

I have 2 classes, A and B. A contains properties that I want to use in B.

I want to put all objects I initialize in B into an array every time a new object is initialized. With this code, the first object should go to array-position 1, the second object to array-position 2 and so on. The variable n basically determines to which position the object should go.

I know that with "this." I can access individual variables from this object (as you can see with x and y), but I don't know how I can access the object as a whole. You see that I have a comment in my code, which shows what I try to do. It doesn't work, because it's not the proper syntax.

What do I have to put there so it will work?

```
class A{
        private int x, y;
        private static int n;
        A(int x, int y){
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                n++;
                //B.object[n] = this.object;
                //I tried this but it doesn't work
        };
}

class B{
        public static A[] object = new A[10];
        public static void main(){
                A object1 = new A(1,2);
                A object2 = new A(3,4);
                A object3 = new A(5,6);
        };
}
```

Comment: that's where the 'this' keyword comes in, but you don't have instances you can contact, because you are working with static methods.

Comment: `object` is not defined in class `A` hence the compiler error.

Comment: use `B.object[n] = this;`

Comment: Also, define main as `public static void main(String[] args)` if you want your program to execute

Comment: I don't intend to execute class A, that's why I don't need a main-method there.

Comment: @Rismosch  You can accept my answer if it helps

Answer (score 1):

Your **`object` reference inside `B` class holds an array of `A` types**, so you need to simply set `B.object[n] = this;` as shown below (Here, `this` itself represents the current `A` object, so no need to say `this.object`):

```
class A{
    private int x, y;
    private static int n;
    A(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        n++;
        B.object[n] = this;
    };
}



class B{
        public static A[] object = new A[10];
        public static void main(String[] args){
                A object1 = new A(1,2);
                A object2 = new A(3,4);
                A object3 = new A(5,6);
        };
}
```

Also, in Java, `main` method takes `String[]` as input arguments (shown above) which will be the method executed by the JVM at the start (though with `main()`, the code compiles, but JVM does not invoke it at the start).

---

But as a side note, remember that what you are trying do creates **circular dependencies (class A depends on class B and then class B depends on class A)**, so avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Although javaguy's solution solves your problem, it will probably cause the compiler to give a warning about a "leaking this" in the constructor.

This could be potentially dangerous in a multithreaded environment because it allows you to get hold of a reference to `A` (via `B.object`) before `A` has fully run through its constructor.

A better pattern in this case would probably be to have a static helper method in `A` that constructs those objects for you, adds them to the list and then returns a reference to them.

```
class A{
    private static int n;

    private int x, y;

    public static A createA(int x, int y){
        A result = new A(x, y);
        n++;
        B.object[n] = result;
        return result;
    }

    private A(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}



class B{
        public static A[] object = new A[10];
        public static void main(String[] args){
                A object1 = createA(1,2);
                A object2 = createA(3,4);
                A object3 = createA(5,6);
        }
}
```

By making the constructor of A private, you ensure that `new A(1,2)` won't work from another class, so you *have* to use the helper method to get an instance.

Comment: javaguy actually solved my problem pretty well. I only learned that with "this." I can access object variables, without realizing that "this" is the object itself. I didn't knew that before. Also I tested javaguys code and it did exactly what I wanted.